# Set human readable units for histogram bucket "le" label?

Tags: grafana

I am visualizing the distribution of values in a Prometheus bucket – which contains latency of a long-running process measured in seconds – in Grafana using a Bar Gauge:

[image]

The bucket increments, shown along the bottom of the green bars, are measured in seconds. However these buckets are very much **not human readable**, for example the second most common value in the chart is 61440 seconds.

[image]

If this were a *value* then I know I can tell Grafana that the units are "seconds" and it would automatically translate the value to "17 hours", but actually this is the *label* `le` on the Prometheus metric.

I've tried using transformations to re-label the labels, but then each bucket becomes cumulative rather than showing the delta for each bucket!

[image]

Is it possible to get a more human readable display of the bucket labels here?

I'd like to solve this at the Grafana layer if possible, but I understand I could change my buckets to minutes or hours units (at the cost of data resolution), which would make 61440 appear as 1024 or 17 respectively.

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot convert those labels as this can be done to value. Closest thing I can imagine is to divide every `le` by 3600 with transformation, to get hours, but this will result in you having same problem, but for lower values.

Comment: I did look at transformations! I can't see any that allow you to apply math to label values though.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot convert labels in a "nice" way, how this can be done to value, with different units depending on size of the number. Closest thing I can imagine useful for described situation is to divide every `le` by 3600 with Transformation, to get hours. It will result in you having basically the same, but for lower values.

How to divide label values by fixed number:

1. Switch format of the query from *Heatmap* to *Table* (options under query).
2. In panel options, segment *Value options* select show *All values*.
3. Apply transformation *Add field from calculation*:

   - Mode: *Binary operation*
   - Operation: `le` `/` `60`
   - Alias: leave as suggested
   - Replace all fields: *No*
4. Apply transformation *Organize fields by name*, and hide all labels except for `le/60` and `Value`. This is to show legend under bars as it was before.
5. Apply transformation *Convert field type*:

   - Field `le / 60` as *String*.

Last step is to make Grafana recognize label as a string and put it into legend of the item.

Comment: Good catch! I changed that, and now I actually see data, but I had to change it back from _Table_ to _Heat Map_ or else the buckets would be *cumulative* rather than showing the delta for each bucket.

Comment: Ahhh but then if I use _Table_ it doesn't use the updated labels :facepalm: